# C#: access a class property when the property identifier is known as a string

Tags: c#, linq, string, linq-to-entities, properties

I'm using LINQ to Entities on a database which structure is not known in advance. I use reflection to retrieve the information, and now have a list of strings with all the table names. Because I use LINQ, I also have the datasource encapsulated in a C# class (linqContext), with each table being a property of that class.

What I want to achieve is this:
Assume one of the strings in the table names list is "Employees". This is known in code, I want to do the following:

```
linqContext.Employees.DoSomethingHere();
```

Is this possible? I know that if all the propertie were just items in a list, I could use the string as indexer, `linqContext["Employees"]`. However, this is not the case :(

Comment: You could try to find the needed entity type through reflection and then use the GetTable method of the DataContext class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly I wouldn't use reflection to get this information, I would use the MetadataWorkspace property of the ObjectContext as this already has the information. Something like this:

```
EntityContainer container = context.MetadataWorkspace
    .GetEntityContainer(context.DefaultContainerName, DataSpace.CSpace);
var setNames = container.BaseEntitySets.Select(b =>b.Name);
```

Once you have the set names you can get the data from a specific set as follows:

```
context.CreateQuery<T>("[" + entitySetName + "]");
```

The generic repository I use actually searches the container for the entity set that matches a given type so that calling code can just pass the type in and get back the appropriate collection.

Answer (score 0):

Use reflection to either retrieve the named property of the DataContext, or to retrieve the entity type and then call DataContext.GetTable(type).

Answer (score -1):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.reflection.fieldinfo(VS.90).aspx